# The mass of components in a binary system for given largest and smallest distance

Tags: physics, astronomy

I try to calculate the mass of the component stars in a binary system.
I only have the period and the largest and smallest distance between them and know how to use them to get the total mass.

To my knowledge, I think I need the distance from one of the stars to the barycenter.

Is that possible to calculate each mass of the component members with this information?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, if you only have the period `T` and the largest `a_max` and smallest `a_min` distance between the two stars, as you pointed out, you can calculate the total mass, using the formula

```
mass_1 + mass_2 = (2*pi / T)^2 * ((a_min + a_max)^3 / G)
```

However, you cannot calculate the individual masses solely from this information, because the prescribed data, the period `T` and the largest `a_max` and smallest `a_min` distance, are for the relative postion of the stars, not the individual.

What do I mean. Assume you have two stars whose motion has the parameters given above. Then, by Newtonian mechanics, let us assume your coordinate system is placed at the barycenter and if you denote the position vectors `r1` and `r2` pointing from the barycenter to the respective stars, then, the equations of motion are

```
(d/dt)^2 r1 = - ( mass_2*G / |r2 - r1|^3 )*(r1 - r2)
(d/dt)^2 r2 = - ( mass_1*G / |r2 - r1|^3 )*(r2 - r1)
```

If you subtract the first vector differential equation from the second, and you set `r = r2 - r1`, you obtain the vector differential equation (3 scalar differential equations and 3 scalar variables, the 3D coordinates of the relative position vector `r`)

```
(d/dt)^2 r = - ( (mass_1 + mass_2)*G / |r|^3 ) * r
```

This is the classical vector differential equation that describes the time-evolution of the relative position vector `r` between the two stars. The information you have, the period `T` and the largest `a_max` and smallest `a_min`, can be used to find a specific solution to the last equation above, the one for `r`, which gives you the relative motion `r = r(t)` between the two stars with the prescribed properties. However, the motion of any pair of stars with arbitrary masses `mass_1` and `mass_2`, that sum up to the same value `mass_1 + mass_2`, will provide a solution to the vector differential equation

```
(d/dt)^2 r = - ( (mass_1 + mass_2)*G / |r|^3 ) * r
```

and among all such solution there will be some that posses the desired properties: period `T` and the largest `a_max` and smallest `a_min`. Observe that `T`, `a_min` and `a_max` are properties of the vector `r` and not so much properties of the individual `r1` and `r2`, which tells you that you cannot find the individual masses.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I also think I need more information.